# How to convert the 50000 txt file into csv

Tags: python-3.x, csv, text

I have many text files. I tried to convert the txt files into a single CSV file, but it is taking a huge time. I put the code on run mode at night and I slept, it processed only 4500 files, but still morning it is running.
There is any way to fast way to convert the text files into csv?

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob
from tqdm import tqdm

# create empty dataframe
csvout = pd.DataFrame(columns =["ID","Delivery_person_ID" ,"Delivery_person_Age" ,"Delivery_person_Ratings","Restaurant_latitude","Restaurant_longitude","Delivery_location_latitude","Delivery_location_longitude","Order_Date","Time_Orderd","Time_Order_picked","Weather conditions","Road_traffic_density","Vehicle_condition","Type_of_order","Type_of_vehicle", "multiple_deliveries","Festival","City","Time_taken (min)"])

# get list of files



file_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "train/", "*.txt"))

for filename in tqdm(file_list):
    # next file/record
    mydict = {}
    with open(filename) as datafile:
        # read each line and split on "  " space
        for line in tqdm(datafile):
            # Note: partition result in 3 string parts, "key", "   ", "value"
            # array slice third parameter [::2] means steps=+2
            # so only take 1st and 3rd item
            name, var = line.partition("   ")[::2]
            mydict[name.strip()] = var.strip()
        # put dictionary in dataframe
        csvout = csvout.append(mydict, ignore_index=True)

# write to csv
csvout.to_csv("train.csv", sep=";", index=False)
```

Here is my example text file.

```
ID                                     0xb379
Delivery_person_ID             BANGRES18DEL02
Delivery_person_Age                 34.000000
Delivery_person_Ratings              4.500000
Restaurant_latitude                 12.913041
Restaurant_longitude                77.683237
Delivery_location_latitude          13.043041
Delivery_location_longitude         77.813237
Order_Date                         25-03-2022
Time_Orderd                             19:45
Time_Order_picked                       19:50
Weather conditions                     Stormy
Road_traffic_density                      Jam
Vehicle_condition                           2
Type_of_order                           Snack
Type_of_vehicle                       scooter
multiple_deliveries                  1.000000
Festival                                   No
City                            Metropolitian
Time_taken (min)                    33.000000
```

Comment: Instead of building up `my_dict` and `csvout` in memory, I would be writing each line to the output file as I parsed it, with suitable buffering of course. Or at least the entire content of each source file, rather than waiting until the end.

Comment: Check out my answer for a hopefully at light speed running code.

Comment: How many rows are there in each file?

Comment: Why  are you using `tqdm`? Don't you think the overhead of drawing a progress bar is contributing to the time? Also why not use the Python `csv` module directly instead of incurring the Pandas overhead cost?

Answer (score 0):

CSV is a very simple data format for which you don't need any sophisticated tools to handle. Just text and separators.

In your hopefully simple case there is no need to use pandas and dictionaries.

Except your datafiles are corrupt missing some columns or having some additional columns to skip. But even in this case you can handle such issues better within your own code so you have more control over it and are able to get results within seconds.

Assuming your datafiles are not corrupt having all columns in the right order with no missing columns or having additional ones (so you can rely on their proper formatting), just try this code:

```
from time import perf_counter as T
sT = T()
filesProcessed = 0
columns =["ID","Delivery_person_ID" ,"Delivery_person_Age" ,"Delivery_person_Ratings","Restaurant_latitude","Restaurant_longitude","Delivery_location_latitude","Delivery_location_longitude","Order_Date","Time_Orderd","Time_Order_picked","Weather conditions","Road_traffic_density","Vehicle_condition","Type_of_order","Type_of_vehicle", "multiple_deliveries","Festival","City","Time_taken (min)"]
import glob, os
file_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "train/", "*.txt"))
csv_lines = []
csv_line_counter = 0
for filename in file_list:
    filesProcessed += 1
    with open(filename) as datafile:
        csv_line = ""
        for line in datafile.read().splitlines():
            # print(line)
            var = line.partition("  ")[-1]
            csv_line += var.strip() + ';'
        csv_lines.append(str(csv_line_counter)+';'+csv_line[:-1])
        csv_line_counter += 1
with open("train.csv", "w") as csvfile:
    csvfile.write(';'+';'.join(columns)+'\n')
    csvfile.write('\n'.join(csv_lines))
eT = T()
print(f'> {filesProcessed=}, {(eT-sT)=:8.6f}')
```

**I guess you will get the result in a speed beyond your expectations (in seconds, not minutes or hours)**

On my computer, estimating from processing time of 100 files the time required for 50.000 files will be about 3 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code! I tried your code , but  My Ccsv file is not in a good format, when reading CSV file using pandas, The columns' names and data are coming (;) separate values, not in table format.

Comment: Does the code run as fast as I have bragged it will?

Comment: How should the first lines of the proper csv file good for pandas table format reading look like? Please post them.

Comment: Please try the updated code in my answer which now writes a ..csv file in pandas table format  including pandas dataframe index.

Answer (score 0):

I could not replicate. I took the example data file and created 5000 copies of it. Then I ran your code using `tqdm` and without. The below shows without:

```
import time
import csv
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm

csvout = pd.DataFrame(columns =["ID","Delivery_person_ID" ,"Delivery_person_Age" ,"Delivery_person_Ratings","Restaurant_latitude","Restaurant_longitude","Delivery_location_latitude","Delivery_location_longitude","Order_Date","Time_Orderd","Time_Order_picked","Weather conditions","Road_traffic_density","Vehicle_condition","Type_of_order","Type_of_vehicle", "multiple_deliveries","Festival","City","Time_taken (min)"])
file_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "sample_files/", "*.txt"))

t1 = time.time()
for filename in file_list:
    # next file/record
    mydict = {}
    with open(filename) as datafile:
        # read each line and split on "  " space
        for line in datafile:
            # Note: partition result in 3 string parts, "key", "   ", "value"
            # array slice third parameter [::2] means steps=+2
            # so only take 1st and 3rd item
            name, var = line.partition("   ")[::2]
            mydict[name.strip()] = var.strip()
        # put dictionary in dataframe
        csvout = csvout.append(mydict, ignore_index=True)

# write to csv
csvout.to_csv("train.csv", sep=";", index=False)
t2 = time.time()
print(t2-t1)
```

The times I got where:

```
tqdm        33 seconds
no tqdm     34 seconds
```

Then I ran using the `csv` module:

```
t1 = time.time()
with open('output.csv', 'a', newline='') as csv_file:
    columns =["ID","Delivery_person_ID" ,"Delivery_person_Age" ,"Delivery_person_Ratings","Restaurant_latitude","Restaurant_longitude","Delivery_location_latitude","Delivery_location_longitude","Order_Date","Time_Orderd","Time_Order_picked","Weather conditions","Road_traffic_density","Vehicle_condition","Type_of_order","Type_of_vehicle", "multiple_deliveries","Festival","City","Time_taken (min)"]
    mydict = {} 
    d_Writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=columns, delimiter=',') 
    d_Writer.writeheader()  
    for filename in file_list:
        with open(filename) as datafile:
            for line in datafile:
                name, var = line.partition("   ")[::2]
                mydict[name.strip()] = var.strip()
            d_Writer.writerow(mydict)
t2 = time.time()
print(t2-t1)
```

The time for this was:

`csv         0.32231569290161133 seconds`.

Answer (score -1):

Try it like this.

```
import glob
with open('my_file.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
    for path in glob.glob('./*.txt'):
        with open(path) as txt_file:
            txt = txt_file.read() + '\n'
            csv_file.write(txt)
```

Comment: Try it why? Mere code is not an answer. You have to explain. And this code does not produce CSV. It merely copies files. You don't need a program for that.